# Pyrogram, telegram server synchronization error

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

i built a telegram bot with pyrogram, didn't have any issues until now, the code worked perfectly, suddenly i started getting this error every time i start the bot:
pyrogram.errors.BadMsgNotification: [16] The msg_id is too low, the client time has to be synchronized.
every time i need to delete the session file in order for the bot to start( im using pyrogram 1.4.16)
knowing that my local time is definitely synchronized, plus in pyrogram's docuentation it says that starting from pyrogram 1.0 the api doesn't depend on local time to but on an internal clock.
(i tried deploying the bot on google cloud to make sure, and i got the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

After 25 December 2023 I got the same error and I've solved upgrading the library using:

`pip install pyrogram --upgrade`

I report the formal error that I got:

`pyrogram Exception: [16] msg_id too low, the client time has to be synchronized`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and what I did was to update my Pyrogram package in my requirements.txt file. I was running Pyrogram 2.0.63 and updated it to the latest as of this writing which is 2.0.106.
I redeployed again and the error was no more.

Comment: thank you very much!
i've tried updating pyrogram before, it solved the issue but the bot stopped responding turns out there were some drastic changes starting from pyrogram 2 
after i saw your answer i tried again and  it worked!
you're  a life saver bro, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, Usually in software versioning when the first number changes, it usually means the changes are significant and may not be backward compatible with the previous releases. So a change from 1.x.x to 2.x.x might mean there are some breaking changes. It's much better to go through the changelogs.